# How to open new route with MemoryRouter in Electron?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I'm using [Electron-React-Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) to developing my app and I'm new to both Electron and React.

The boilerplate uses [ReactRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main) package to handle the route of the app, and I want to create a new window which shows content in specified route when user click a button. (e.g.: Opening `Settings` page in a new window which at the route `/settings`)

---

##### My Implementation

First I add a new route and set its element to `SettingsPage` component

```
<MemoryRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path="/settings" element={<SettingsPage />} />
  </Routes>
</MemoryRouter>
```

Then I tried several method to open the new page

**Electron `window.open()`**

First, I use the method in [Electron Docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/window-open), and use a button to call `window.open()` like below

```html
<button
    onClick={function () {
        const childWindow = window.open('/settings', 'modal')
        childWindow.electron = window.electron;
    }}>
    SETTINGS
</button>
```

It did opened a new window, however it failed to direct to the correct content (the `SettingsPage` component I set before) and fallback to the HomePage with console log below

```
...
...
[1] <i> [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to '/index.html'
...
Rewriting GET /settings to /index.html
```

I'm using the default file structure and default webpack settings of the Electron-React-Boilerplate I memtioned at first, and seems that webpack server could not resolve the address `/settings` and just redirect to the `index.html` so I see the HomePage of my app again in the newly opened window.

**react-router-dom `<Link to="">`**

I also tried the method in the ReactRouter as below

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Link to="/settings">SETTINGS<Link>
```

This time when I click `SETTINGS` link, it worked and redirect the page to the `SettingsPage`, however this method will NOT open a new window and just redirect the page in the current window.

I add `target="_blank"` and use code like `<Link to="/settings" target="_blank">SETTINGS<Link>`, however once I add the `target="_blank"` it failed again, and like the method before, the new window fallback to `index.html` and show `HomePage` of my electron app.

Besides, the windows created by `<Link to="/settings" target="_blank">` has another issue, which is that the new window created by `<Link>` do not have access to `window.electron` property, which I exposed to the original window before using the `preload.ts`

**a href**

I tried to use `<a href="/contest">`, however this time it completely doesn't work no matter if I add the `target="_blank"`

---

##### In Addition

After severl trys, I also try to change the <MemoryRouter> to <BrowerRouter>, this time, `<Link to="/settings" target="_blank">` can open the correct route in new window **in dev env**, however still meeting `window.electron undefined` error. but this time when app is packaged, the router was broken completely and the app even cannot load the HomePage. I searched on the Internet and see that says BrowserRouter can not work properly with some file based router env like Electron

---

Is the issue relevant to the way the boilerplate handles routing? Or it's just because my code is wrong? How can I open a new window and show content of a particular route (like `/settings` in the example) with ReactRouter's `MemoryRouter`?

Comment: The "trouble" of using a `MemoryRouter` is that it isn't coupled to the URL in the address bar, so I don't know of, or think there's a way, to open the app in a new browser context to a specific route. Maybe you could pass a queryString parameter and use vanilla JS to read it and effect an internal navigation action to a target route path. It looks like you are in a DOM environment though, is there a reason you are using a `MemoryRouter`? I think using the `HashRouter` will yield you better results.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your reply, 
I have tried change the router to `HashRouter` and it works with both `window.open()` and `<Link>`, however `HashRouter` doesn't work in dev env, so I add a check logic to use `BrowserRouter` in dev env and use a `HashRouter` in prod env and this works well in my case.

Comment: IMO the `HashRouter` should also work in a development environment, but glad to hear you've a working solution. Cheers!